# Dynamic proxy setting in package.json

Tags: reactjs, express, dotenv

I am learning how to use express together with a create-react-app. One of the internal wiring would be to set a `proxy` keyword in the package.json for the client side. However, I am interested to know how to dynamically inject a value into that keyword so that i can easily deploy the code anywhere without having to manually changing the `proxy` url each time.

I am not sure if i am asking the question the right way, but this is how I need it to be. I already have a .env folder within the different servers. So i just need to know if there is a way i can do it with the .env files.

Thanks